# Problems encoding a Bayesian Network when using MultinomialDistribution

Tags: probability-or-statistics, warning-messages, distributions

### Short description of the encountered problem

I am getting an error when using a `MultinomialDistribution` to encode a conditional probability distribution (CPD) within the joint probability distribution of a Bayesian Network while it works completely fine as a standalone distribution. A bug?

### A simple Bayesian Network taken from Daphne Koller's book on PGM

As a minimal example, I am trying to encode the first three nodes of the Bayesian Network that is given on page 53 in *Probabilistic Graphical Models (2009)*, by *Daphne Koller* and *Nir Friedman*:

[image: BayesianNetworkExample]

### Encoding the joint Probability Distribution P(I,D,G)

I am encoding the Bayesian Network given by the nodes *Difficulty* (easy,hard) of the class taken by a student, *Intelligence* (low,high) of the student and *Grade* (g1=A, g2=B, g3=C) achieved in the class as follows:

```
distI = BernoulliDistribution[ 0.3 ]; (* probability of high intelligence *)
distD = BernoulliDistribution[ 0.4 ]; (* probability of hard class *)

grade = Function[ { g1, g2, g3 },
    { g1, g2, g3 }.Range[3]
]; (* map the vector of grades onto the set {1,2,3} *)

(* conditional distribution of the grade *)
cpdG = Function[ { i, d },
    With[
      {
        n = 1,
        p = Piecewise[
                {
                  { {  0.3,  0.4, 0.3  }, i == 0 && d == 0 },
                  { { 0.05, 0.25, 0.7  }, i == 0 && d == 1 },
                  { {  0.9, 0.08, 0.02 }, i == 1 && d == 0 },
                  { {  0.5,  0.3, 0.2  }, i == 1 && d == 1 }
                }
            ]
      },
      TransformedDistribution[ 
          grade @@ {g1,g2,g3}, 
          {g1,g2,g3} \[Distributed] MultinomialDistribution[ n, p ]
      ]
    ]
];

(* the joint distribution P(I,D,G) as given by the chain rule *)
distB = ProbabilityDistribution[
    PDF[ distI, i] PDF[ distD, d] PDF[ cpdG[ i, d ], g ],
    {i, 0, 1, 1},
    {d, 0, 1, 1},
    {g, 1, 3, 1}
]
```

But this will give the follwing error message (repeatedly):

[image: errormessage]

Note, that the conditional distribution nicely works on its own:

```
PDF[ cpdG[1, 1], 2 ]
```

> 0.3

**What is the problem here?**

### Update

The `MultinomialDistribution` can be replaced with the `EmpiricalDistribution`, which avoids some problems:

```
(* conditional distribution of the grade *)
cpdG = Function[ { i, d },
    With[
      {
        p = Piecewise[
                {
                  { {  0.3,  0.4, 0.3  }, i == 0 && d == 0 },
                  { { 0.05, 0.25, 0.7  }, i == 0 && d == 1 },
                  { {  0.9, 0.08, 0.02 }, i == 1 && d == 0 },
                  { {  0.5,  0.3, 0.2  }, i == 1 && d == 1 }
                }
            ]
      },
      EmpiricalDistribution[ p -> Range[3] ]
    ]
];
```

Then we do probabilistic inference using `Probability`:

```
Probability[ g == 1 \[Conditioned] i == 1, {i,d,g} \[Distributed] distB ]
```

> 0.74

But to my disappointment this will fail for the full Bayesian Network -- but that should probably go into a separate question...

Comment: `BernoulliDisztribution` is apparently misspelled.

Comment: Fixed a couple of typos just now. Everything should be (not)working as indicated... :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Explanation and Solution given by WRI support

I just received an answer from support:

> What seems to be the issue is the Piecewise definition in cpdG. When evaluating ProbabilityDistribution[...], the values for i,d, and g are substituted after the definition is made, so the Piecewise definition remains general, which conflicts with the MultinomialDistribution. This also explains why the conditional distribution ( such as PDF[cpdG[1,1],2] ) works. Since the values for the variables are known, the piecewise definition within cpdG does not conflict with the MultinomialDistribution.

The solution proposed is the following:

> We can get around this by defining a function that takes i,d, and g as arguments, and returns the value of cpdG for the desired input variables.

```
cpdGtable[ i_, d_, g_ ] := Table[
    PDF[ cpdG[i, d], g ], 
    {i, 0, 1, 1}, {d, 0, 1, 1}, {g, 1, 3, 1}
]

distB = ProbabilityDistribution[
    PDF[distI, i] PDF[distD, d] cpdGtable[i,d,g],
    {i,0,1,1},{d,0,1,1},{g,1,3,1}
];
```

Unfortunately this approach does not seem to work out as intended:

```
Probability[ g == 1, {i,d,g} \[Distributed] distB ]
```

> {{{0.3, 0.4, 0.3}, {0.05, 0.25, 0.7}}, {{0.9, 0.08, 0.02}, {0.5, 0.3,
> 0.2}}}

### Alternate Solution using Indicator Functions

As the use of [`Piecewise`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Piecewise.html) seems to be an issue when using [`MultinomialDistribution`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MultinomialDistribution.html) using  [`Boole`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Boole.html) instead will work:

```
(* code up to this point as in the OP *)
cpdG = Function[ {i, d},
    With[
      {
        n = 1,
        p = Plus[
              {0.3 , 0.4 , 0.3}  Boole[i==0 && d==0],
              {0.05, 0.25, 0.7}  Boole[i==0 && d==1],
              {0.9 , 0.08, 0.02} Boole[i==1 && d==0],
              {0.5 , 0.3 , 0.2}  Boole[i==1 && d==1]
            ]
      },
      TransformedDistribution[ 
        grade@@{g1,g2,g3},
        {g1,g2,g3} \[Distributed] MultinomialDistribution[n,p]
      ]
    ]
];

distB = ProbabilityDistribution[
   PDF[distI, i] PDF[distD, d] PDF[cpdG[i, d], g], 
   {i, 0, 1, 1}, {d, 0, 1, 1}, {g, 1, 3, 1}
];
```

Now everything works out fine, and the probability for getting an A given a high IQ turns out to be 74%:

```
Probability[ g==1 \[Conditioned] i==1, {i,d,g} \[Distributed] distB ]
```

> 0.74

### UPDATE

> We can get around this by defining a function that takes i,d, and g as arguments, and returns the value of cpdG for the desired input variables.

While it has been awhile, I lately came back to this question and we can indeed make the original approach work out by making sure, that the `PDF` within `ProbabilityDistribution` is defined with concise values, i.e., we have to make sure it is not evaluate too soon.

A very simple and straightforward apporach is to define a function `cpdfG` which will provide the correct `PDF` for node `G` when it is given *numerical* values:

```
cpdfG[ i_?NumericQ, d_?NumericQ, g_?NumericQ ] := With[
    { dist = cpdG[ i, d ] }
    ,
    PDF[ dist, g ]
]
```

Leaving everything as given in the original post, we define the *joint probability distribution* as follows:

```
distB = ProbabilityDistribution[
    PDF[ distI, i] PDF[ distD, d] cpdfG[ i, d, g ],
    {i, 0, 1, 1},
    {d, 0, 1, 1},
    {g, 1, 3, 1}
]

Probability[ g == 1, {i, d, g} \[Distributed] distB ]

(* 0.362 *)
```